# Is it possible to authorize the admin in devise to create a new page in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a project in Rails and I want the admin in devise to be able to create a new page. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes it's possible. I would suggest using a CMS (Content Management System) in your app. Search "rails CMS" on Google.